# How to configure Laravel API to port 8000 with apache2?

Tags: php, laravel, apache2

I am new to apache2 and DigitalOccean. I have a Laravel project API. I installed php mysql and apache2 on DigitalOcean server. I want to access the API with IP address and Port number 8000 (Like http://139.59.28.165:8000) (Port 8000 enabled in firewall). But when I browse the link http://139.59.28.165:8000, it shows `This site can’t be reached`.

[image: This site cannot be reached]

But without port number it shows the directory

[image]

But I want with IP address and Port number like this:
[image]

**Current DocumentRoot(/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf)**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/crm-api


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

Create a configuration file on the server name by
`sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/139.59.28.165:8000.conf`
and add the following contents

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
        ServerName 139.59.28.165:8000
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/crm-api/public

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <Directory /var/www/crm-api>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Run the following command

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
sudo a2ensite 139.59.28.165:8000.conf
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Add the following in the `hosts` file `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 139.59.28.165
```

And also add your port in `ports configuration` `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`

```
Listen 8000
```

Don't forget to restart the apache2 `sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 1):

Change the port in your vhost to 8000

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/crm-api


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Also you may want to set the DocumentRoot to **/var/www/crm-api/public**

Laravel specifies that the public folder should be the document root.

Then go ahead and restart apache.

Comment: Did you restart apache after? I forgot to mention it.

Comment: Yeah! I restarted `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: Are you still able to access it without a port? (port 80)

Comment: Without port, It loads Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page http://139.59.28.165/

Comment: Any other changes?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the port of your virtualhost to 8000
And add public at the end of DocumentRoot.
desable an enable your config.

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>

   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   DocumentRoot /var/www/crm-api/public


  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

It's like apache2 don't listen to 8000
you have to anable it by editing /etc/apache2/port.conf
 and restart the server

```
Listen 80
Listen 8000
<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

 <IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
 </IfModule>
```

## vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet

Comment: It says `This site can’t be reached`

Comment: After add `Listen 8000` then restart. It says `Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
`

Comment: How to change it ?

Comment: can you post the content of this file? /etc/apache2/port.conf

Comment: try to restart the server again, when i change the port.conf file and run th restart command it says the same errors  but when i re-run it it start well and i can reach the server with port 8000

Comment: if it not start run this command: journalctl | tail and tell me what you get

Comment: But while restarts it echos `Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

Comment: your server is now reacheable at port 8000 check it

Comment: it just remind  right config file of your virtualhost

Comment: Sorry! unable to understand

Comment: add this line to /etc/hosts file:  127.0.0.1     139.59.28.165 and restart the server

Comment: There is no `hosts` file

Comment: with nano /etc/hosts i can edit the content of hosts file on my apache2 server. i don't knwo why you don't have it

Comment: any version problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your port from your local server if you are using wamp or xampp you should change it from Apache config file and make it 8000 instead of 80

Comment: Where is the Apache config file ?

Comment: What program are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 server